# Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.9, SQLite 3 incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8

I know that question with same title has been asked almost 6 month ago.

I have Googled for this problem and I have not found any working solution.

Has there been any fixes for this very critical problem?

I need to get my website running ASAP. Just to get the site up and running I'm even ready to add utf8 conversion methods to all my variables or risk to upgrade to Rails 3 beta

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Rails 3 already has a fix? Hoozah! Is using beta too adventurous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re the reason this was happening, here is a link to a similar question that was asked more recently than yours together with a response:

- [ruby 1.9 + sinatra incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223518/ruby-1-9-sinatra-incompatible-character-encodings-ascii-8bit-and-utf-8/3224119#3224119)

Check out this excellent blog post for an overview of the underlying problem and some possible solutions:

- http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/